# Regular expression validation for date and gender format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text box,user will enter age and gender in textbox.i want to put validation for age and gender.the user may enter **47Yrs 1Mths 5Days/F** or **47Yrs 1Mths/M** or **47Yrs 2Days/F** or **5Days** or **45Yrs**.so for this i want one format of regular expression validation.

Here is my code but it is not working

```
/^[0-9](?:[0-9]*)(?:Years|Days|Months|Year|Month|Day) (?:[0-9])(?:[0-9]*)([?:Mths]) (?:[0-9])(?:[0-9]*)([?:Days])\/(?:M|F)$/
```

Comment: which platform/editor are you using?

Comment: i am using java platform and i want to put validation in js

Comment: Try this one.  ([0-9]+Yrs)\s*([0-9]*Mths|)\s*([0-9]Days|)(\/|)(M|F|)

Comment: Rather try [`^(?:[0-9]+Y(?:ea)?rs(?: +|(?:\/[MF])?$))?(?:[0-9]+Mths(?: +|(?:\/[MF])?$))?(?:[0-9]+Days)?(?:\/[MF])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/lD0vI1/1). Or simpler but a bit less precise - [`^(?: ?[0-9]+(Y(?:ea)?rs|Mths|Days))+(?:\/[MF])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/lD0vI1/2) as it allows a leading space. To get rid of it, you will need to unroll it a bit like [`^[0-9]+(?:Y(?:ea)?rs|Mths|Days)(?: [0-9]+(?:Y(?:ea)?rs|Mths|Days))*(?:\/[MF])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/lD0vI1/3).

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(?:[0-9]+Y(?:ea)?rs(?: +|(?:\/[MF])?$))?(?:[0-9]+Mths(?: +|(?:\/[MF])?$))?(?:[0-9]+Days)?(?:\/[MF])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD0vI1/4)

**DETAILS**:

```
^                                             # Start of string
  (?:[0-9]+Y(?:ea)?rs(?: +|(?:\/[MF])?$))?    # Number+Years + optional spaces OR /M OR /F
  (?:[0-9]+Mths(?: +|(?:\/[MF])?$))?          # Number+Months + optional spaces OR /M OR /F
  (?:[0-9]+Days)?(?:\/[MF])?                  # Number+Days and optional /M OR /F
$
```